# CSS - Set all DIVs Centered

Tags: html, css

**I *almost* figured out what I need - see my answer, it's 90% complete**

**Background**

I've finally transferred my website, as per a friends suggestion, from tables holding the images for the background to CSS.

When creating the original site (with tables), I couldn't get the page both horizontally centered and vertically. I used all the tags available, but it just wouldn't work. It was weird.

I got hold of JS to set content to the right place on the screen dependant on the window height and width, on onLoad() and onResize(). The Javascript was as follows:

```
function getWindowHeight() {
var windowHeight = 0;
if (typeof(window.innerHeight) == 'number') {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
else {
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else {
        if (document.body && document.body.clientHeight) {
            windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
    }
}
return windowHeight;
}

// Vertically center the #content div
function setContent() 
{
if (document.getElementById) {
    var windowHeight = getWindowHeight();
    if (windowHeight > 0) {
        var contentElement = document.getElementById('body');
        var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
        var contentWidth = contentElement.offsetWidth;
        if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
            contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
            contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
        }
        else {
            contentElement.style.position = 'static';
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Old to New**

The original HTML uses tables to display everything. Very poor! So I've converted to CSS.

[Here is the new page.](http://tasks.j7mbo.co.uk).

**My Question**

I need to center all my divs on the page, just like it was with tables. However, using the above JS in conjunction with `align="center"` places everything far too much to the right.

How do I center everything on screen so that when the screen is resized, it all stays in the center?

I have looked at containers, edited the Javascript above to account for .left and more. I need that tiny bit of code tailored to what I have. Can someone lend a quick hand, I've been at this for half a day. Thanks!

Basic code for what I want to center:

```
<body bgcolor="#a5a5a5" onLoad="setContent();" onResize="setContent();">
<div id="body" align="center">
    <!-- Horizontal alignment handled with align tag, vertical via Javascript -->
    <div id="img-01"><img src="images/img_01.jpg" width="12" height="584" alt="" align="center"></div>
    <div id="img-02"><img src="images/img_02.jpg" width="365" height="17" alt="" align="center"></div>
// ... and more images in divs, up to about 23
```

How do I center all these? Just thought I'd note that originally it was a load of seperate div imgs, but I added the body div because it is referenced in the JS. When I had tables, it was just one div with all the table cells inside it, which is why it worked.

EDIT: When I DO think I have a horizontal center working, it seems more 75% to the right instead. Confused, please can someone help? :)

Comment: Do you really use javascript to put loads of images on your page at specific places? Can't see how this could go wrong...

Comment: I tried to point out it was a last resort, totally not what I wanted but my only option :)

Comment: Why is using images your only option?

Comment: I'm on a strict time limit with this Uni project and getting the look of it perfect isn't the most important thing going on here. However I personally want it to look as good as possible and I'm learning things all the time... I'm not going to get marked up or down depending on whether or not I use images, they're going to be looking at the database architectures I use within my project and implementing the MVC approach, NOT how it looks. That's just for me to be proud of sorting out. :)

Comment: oh I see.  Well disregard what I said in my answer below then about images!  Though to tell you the truth, it still would be a lot easier if you just made your images all one graphic and then stuck that image in a container that you give a width and height to, then set margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto for horizontal centering.  The vertical centering, I am not so good at. Perhaps someone else could chime in with an answer for that?

Answer (score 4):

Your markup is a complete mess. It's using old, deprecated markup. It's missing a doctype. You are using absolute positioning throughout which is why you can't center it as you wish. You need to sit back and start from square one, learn what current modern practices are and build a very simple, one div version of this so you can get a handle on how things work today. What you show is totally unusable.

This may sound harsh but it is what it is. You are missing the basic fundamentals of web markup today.

Comment: I appreciate your criticism, however a little bit more than "start again from stratch" would be helpful. I have the doctype and more, I only posted a small part of the code.

Comment: I thought I'd point out that I can easily put the width, height etc into CSS. Just need to get everything centered, so a point in THAT direction would be helpful. Nico: there's only a few lines of HTML there and it's a 'mess'!? Well I haven't had this before...

Comment: Modern websites make use of far less `<img />` tags, and don't rely on them for presentation - hence why people are saying your code is messy. Check out [reference.sitepoint.com](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html) to help you learn basic HTML and CSS.

Comment: Just a quick question. As I'm using PHP for my web application, the latest update 5.4.0 (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-5-4-is-here-what-you-must-know/) states : "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 is always sent; so there’s no need to set that HTML meta tag, or send additional headers for UTF-8 compatibility." Alright to leave the DOCTYPE now?

Comment: @Jimbo - The content-type in the header tells the browser it's HTML but that's all. Without a doctype declaration in the document, your page will be rendered in quirks mode. Always supply a doctype. Don't look for ways around it.

Comment: Thanks rob, that was a brief mix-up between Content-Type and DOCTYPE. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, your comment about adding as a background image got me thinking.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body {
background-color:#a5a5a5;
background-image:url('Path to your one big image');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Works in Chrome, IE 7-9, the latest Firefox and Safari.  Image stays in the center of the page no matter how big the browser window is.

Comment: Beautifully simple, I've just put this up on my website tweaked slightly and it's great. Thanks Heather! However, obviously my DIV's will be placed on top with the content in. How do I get these to stick to the background? (I'll make each div in the exact size and position of each part like the title box for example).

Comment: Solved this: involved setting the top and left of DIV's to 50%, then the margin-left and margin-top to the px I wanted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

first throw a class on all those image divs
i'll call mine imageclass

## body {width:100%;}

.imagediv {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}

note: this will work if the images are wrapped inside a containter bigger than they are.
you could actually just use 1 css property here but i did it the long way.

edit- and actually you dont' really need the body {width:100%;}
that should be default and then yur wrapper should be set to 100%(inside of body)

Comment: So I've set all my divs with images inside them to: 
`<div id="img-01" class="imageclass"><img src="images/img_01.jpg" width="12" height="584" alt=""></div>`
And in the CSS:
`.imageclass {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}`

Anything else?

Comment: add a max-width:50%; perhaps.  its really hard to tell without seeing how your page is set up.  do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this link over at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atJeg/) might help you get started.  It is rough and doesn't have but half of your code but you get where it is going, I hope.  Things to keep in mind:

1)the 'align=center' attribute has been deprecated for quite some time...this is a holdover from the days of tables.
2)You honestly don't need to use images to display your page how you want it.  CSS supports box-shadows now and using google fonts or @font-face will get you the font you want right in your page (way better than using images.  Search engines can read your text this way...this is a BIG factor in ranking well in Google Search, BTW).
3)Getting your container div to stay in the horizontal center is very easy, no matter how big your browser window is, using margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto set on your container div.
4)The vertical centering is a bit trickier, but you DON'T have to use Javascript!  I suggest you search for 'vertically centering a div'.

The comments about your code being a mess, well, 10 years ago it would have been how you coded.  Now, CSS makes things a LOT easier but you do need to take some time to learn it and about different browser quirks.  Good luck with this and please post an update!

Comment: Aha now that's more like it. Your jsfiddle link is very informative! However the background images have subtle gradients, that'll be a lot of work just to put it all into CSS. I've learned something though.. I have no idea why I didn't just put the whole thing as one background image!